# Visualise data with different sample sizes

Tags: data-visualization, sample-size

I did a literature review and ended up with a lot of data in the kind of "10 out of 20 studies found x while 4 out of 8 studies found y".

To be more precise; I looked up the contribution of seafood to environmental impact categories in different studies. Here is a short extraction of my data:

[image]

I would like to represent the data somehow now. For example I would like to have a graph that shows how many cases of "Fishing" contributes "33%" compared to "Processing", "Packaging" and so on.

How can I deal with the different sample sizes? Should I select a minimum number of studies to include and if yes, is there any criteria to set that limit?

I don't need to do statistics but would like to have some simple graphs to allow readers a very quick first overview.

Answer (score 2):

A modified bar chart with bar width (height in this case) representing the number of articles may work. This one is rotated by 90 degrees to accommodate the long axis labels.

[image]

There are many other ways as well:

1. Pictogram (use a document icon for each literature) or a barchart that is formatted like a [population pyramid](https://www.google.com/search?q=population+pyramid), one side is present, the other side absent.
2. [Combine bubble chart and pie chart](http://www.improving-visualisation.org/img_uploads/2009-03-10_Tue/2009310111624.jpg) by using the bubble size to represent number of literature and the slices to represent present/absent evidence.
3. As a modification of 2, you may also consider [squarified tree map](https://www.google.com/search?q=squarified+tree+map).